# ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting) ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

getting error whenever i'm trying to ionic build.showing
cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter: Processed 16 source files in 387ms
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)

i changed sdk version and i'm using sdk 30 version also change path.but still getting same error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should arise because of missing local.properties file where the SDK location is stored. Just check if its present in your project, if not just add it with the correct SDK location from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your SDK path to C:\Android\SDK

have a look at my environmental variable settings as under and try once
[image]